# Add a way to dismiss the "Internet Explorer is no longer supported" banner

Tags: feature-request, notification-bar, internet-explorer

When browsing the site using Internet Explorer, a new banner indicating that IE is no longer officially supported appears:

[image: Sorry, we no longer support Internet Explorer]

Unfortunately, there is no way to dismiss this prompt. Can there please be a way to dismiss this prompt? (Especially since there are platforms on which it's not possible to install other browsers, e.g. Windows RT or some older company PCs.)

Comment: Why would you willingly use IE?

Comment: @Zoe I use Windows RT on occasion, on which IE is the only browser you can use and there is no way to install another browser on it.

Comment: @Zoe - My employer has "standardized" on it due to all their intranet tools being written to use it, and does not allow installs of other browsers. I don't use it at home of course, but I have 0 choice in the matter at work.

Comment: @T.E.D. That's not willingly.

Comment: I can see how adding the ability to dismiss the "no longer supported" banner in a browser might be interpreted as supporting that browser.

Comment: @Don'tPanic That would need a level of incompetence where I then wonder how that person managed to sit upright in front of the monitor. And still, you can just name that button "ignore this message" and that problem should be solved.

Comment: @Tom How would the name of a button help someone sit upright?

Comment: @Don'tPanic Sorry, I can't tell you that secret ... at least not yet ;P.

Comment: github makes this much better, there the user has the choice to dismiss the banner. As a workaround you could zap the element with an ad blocker

Comment: @Tom _"That would need a level of incompetence where I then wonder how that person managed to sit upright in front of the monitor."_ That's widespread and well known as [PEBKAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_error#PEBKAC).

Comment: The way you disable it is to upgrade to a supported browser. If you can't, explain to your company how much of an impact their policy to not upgrade to Edge is having to your continued productivity.

Comment: I think the biggest irony here is that you're asking them to make a FR change for IE after they've explicitly said they no longer support IE :P

Comment: direct your complaints at IT

Comment: Ironically, I just hit "Close this Message" on a banner stating "If you think this question is helpful, please consider a comment". It's almost like it's a common practice to have the ability to close banners...

Comment: @samcarter IE supports ad blockers?

Comment: @Zoe If there are no ad blockers, how to use stackexchange? All these banners, questionable ads and fingerprinting made it impossible to use it without ad blockers

Comment: I also am at a workplace that requires IE (although I sneak Edge in) because of custom apps and the AT (assistive technology) to use said apps is aimed at IE.  Government contracts lock you in.  (And I also am only on Stack Exchange at work.)

Comment: Also, as another user trapped in IE for the foreseeable future, what differences are there currently?  Right now, SE looks the same this week as last week (except the banner, which I quickly scroll past), but some sites are very difficult to read in IE due to various choices.  (Example: I have to use old.reddit and not www.reddit, or else the alignment is wonky and half the functionality in a thread seems hidden.)

Comment: @April--Un-SlanderMonica-- We haven't yet removed all the IE-specific code that will break the site. Most notably, the voting buttons will not be floated to the left of the post in IE browsers. Instead, they'll appear as a large block with a ton of blank space on the left and right *above* each post. There will also be overlapping text in a few places.

Comment: @Zoe IE does support ad blockers. EasyList is available as a Tracking Protection List for IE, which effectively gives it ad blocking capabilities.

Comment: @animuson Can you tell us when this is planned to happen? Can someone please address whether or not this banner-dismissal suggestion will be implemented?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yesterday, while logged in via IE I could upvote comments, posts, and questions.  This morning, that functionality is gone.

**Are they REMOVING functionality?**
Is S.E./S.O. Inc. actively changing the codebase in a way designed *specifically* to cause issues with a browser they don't support, or is it a side-effect of some other change?

I am not using this browser by choice - it's the only authorized one where I work (a contract at a federal job, with their IT regulations).  I am pretty sure I am not the only one using IE because it's the only option.

I also see that I can no longer add comments, *or* expand more comments.

Comment: *Is S.E./S.O. Inc. actively changing the codebase in a way designed specifically to cause issues with a browser they don't support?* Nope, that would not make sense. But trust me, even the slightest improvement to the codebase can throw IE into hissy fits if you're not careful. And most of us are tired of being careful with IE in the first place.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi : ‘‘No, Stack Exchange didn’t do *X*, because *X* would not make sense.’’   Citation needed.

Comment: April:  [I’m have the same problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339304/195817 "Did Stack Exchange break the Internet?").

Comment: Accepting this since this appears to be the final resolution. The change in question was to remove all the IE-specific hacks that were present in the code.

Answer (score 22):

IE is still widely used, especially in enterprise environments. One might be actually forced to use it. In this case, the banner becomes only a nuisance, because you just can't switch browsers as you'd wish.

I don't think anyone needs to be actually *reminded everytime* that IE is bad and there are better solutions; it's perfectly possible they would really like to use another browser, but just can't.

You have given your warning; if someone then insists on using IE (or, more likely, just *has* to use it), it's their problem; but forcing a banner upon them is a bit rude.

Comment: Most people are not aware that IE 11 still receives security updates, it even from time to time, receives very minor feature updates (limited to IE11 builds on supported versions of Windows).  Now the Trident engine will never be updated to be feature complete with any of the other current browser engines, which is likely the major reason, Stack Exchange has decided not to support it.  Although, not supporting IE 11, sort of breaks the general policy of supporting browsers that are supported (i.e. by Google, Mozilla, Apple, Microsoft, etc).

Comment: Yes... everything has been working the same today as it has been for the last few years on IE at work. I'd love to dismiss the banner! If I find a function that doesn't work I can remote in a VM on my home LAN, but I highly doubt that use case happening often. I too am forced by work to use IE.

Comment: It is because of this kind of attitude that IE is still used. There should be zero tolerance towards IE in order to kill it already.

Comment: Also a really bad use of screen real-estate. On my setup it takes up something like 10% of the window. That's crazy just for one message.

Comment: @T.E.D. It's a bad use of screen real-estate on a browser that is not supported. There is no reason for a site to make cosmetic changes directed specifically towards a browser that it doesn't support. That's what *unsupported* means.

Comment: @Ludwik You've missed the point here, the site **has** made cosmetic changes directed specifically towards a browser that it doesn't support, and that cosmetic change has caused this discussion because it's annoying.

Comment: @Renan That's just condescending.

Answer (score 14):

**Yes!**

I share your pain due to work IT policies.

A good example of how this can be done is Github, which has a similar message with a helpful "Ignore" button. This is a great compromise:

[image: Github banner]

Comment: The more websites that tell you that IE is no longer supported, the more leverage you get with your tech department to finally get a decent browser. We don't want those in charge of keeping systems up to date to be able to ignore these messages, do we?

Comment: I removed the background info which is less relevant in an answer, you can rollback if you find the edit too radical. Thanks.

Comment: @Cerbrus I work for a large company, with slow IT policy roll-outs. For instance the Windows 7 to Windows 10 upgrade (which includes an update to Edge) is in its 2nd year, and only about 50% complete.

Comment: @Wolfie: The problem is that the browser is a side-effect of upgrading the windows version there... It should've had a higher priority, which it would've had if more employees got warnings like these all over the place. "The internet" puts way too much effort into supporting IE, which makes the upgrade process take way too long.

Comment: @Cerbrus You don't need to convince me, this doesn't apply to my personal computer

Comment: @Cerbrus - In my case, I really don't think problems on my end loading websites contribute to any leverage whatsoever. Updating our intranet tools to support a newer browser costs money, likely a lot of it. OTOH I can be counted on to "find a way" around technical problems (that's kinda my job), and ingnoring my browser complaints is free.

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe that it's a good idea letting users to dismiss that reminder.
They might easily forget about they've done that, and later come here to complain about features not working.

For you, it won't hinder you to work with the SE sites as long you're only use features that still are supported with IE.

Thus I don't think the efforts to realize your feature-request are justifiable, or it's really useful.

Comment: So, you are saying that users are incapable of taking care of themselves?

Comment: @ColumbiasaysReinstateMonica Sure I do: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/338021/add-a-way-to-dismiss-the-internet-explorer-is-no-longer-supported-banner#comment1124807_338021 Just from experience.

Comment: I think half of the Internet doesn't work for them... so getting rid of the banner might be more user friendly.

Comment: @her Why should we leave them in the dark, and risk unwanted complaints and noise?

Comment: But they are already complaining.

Comment: @Her But how would the feature of dismissing make that better?

Comment: Save the state. Dismiss only once. Nobody uses Explorer because they really want to. This banner is just adding insult to an injury.

Comment: _"Nobody uses Explorer because they really want to."_ Some people just don't know any better. Also, the more websites that tell you that IE is no longer supported, the more leverage you get with your tech department to finally get a decent browser.